# Unsupported Operation. A document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in the C stack.

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

My problem seems similar, but the situation is different. I'm using Windows Server 2003 64 Bit with Visual Studio 2010, Crystal Report 13.02.456 Runtime (64 Bit) for framework 4.0 and Crystal reports version for Visual studio 2010.

The report works perfectly in debug mode. 
1.But when it is deployed on IIS at first it started giving jscript 'bobj' missing error. 
2.Later I searched the internet and copied crystalreportviewer13 folder from IIS folder to my application root folder. 
3.The error changed to 'Unsupported Operation. A document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in the C++ stack.'

Any help would be great, as i am unable to find any solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be caused by the path being incorrect when loading the rpt file. Could probably be other things too, but certainly that's one thing to check first.

See forum posts [here](http://scn.sap.com/thread/2011850), [here](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1860995) and [here](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1975259)